# Is it normal for dynamic_rnn() and rnn() to produce different results?

Tags: tensorflow

In the documentation of [dynamic_rnn()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.nn.dynamic_rnn.md) it says:

> This function is functionally identical to the function `rnn` above,
>   but   performs fully dynamic unrolling of `inputs`.

When I use the *exact* same parameters for both dynamic_rnn() and rnn() I get slightly differing results (leaving aside that the input has to be provided in differing formats - the parameter content is the same). I noticed that for the *first* batch the first 16 batch rows give identical results (for both state and output). Everything else of the first and all other batches is unequal.

Given the suspicious base 2 number 16 I suspect that it has to do with numerical issues but I would like some re-assurance on that if possible.

Comment: Are they just a little different? Small differences can happen for a wide variety of reasons. For instance `tanh` results differ slightly depending on how large the vector is, despite tanh being a pointwise function -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2234#issuecomment-217312397

Comment: Yes the differences are indeed very little. Thank you for the hint!